# Change a background image of a style in css using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image

Trying to change the background image of a div class background in CSS using javascript based on a hard-coded variable: See Function below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkLocation() {
        var loctype="UH";
        if(loctype=localonly)
            document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-content').style.backgroundImage="url(./img/LocalConn.jpg)";
        else if(loctype=UH)
            document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-content').style.backgroundImage="url(./img/UHConn.jpg)";
        else
            document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-content').style.backgroundImage="url(./img/MoodleUHConn.jpg)";
            }
</script>
```

Called in HTML page see code below:

```
<div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn"></button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <div class="media">
                        <div class="media-left">
                        <a href="#"> <script type="text/javascript">checkLocation();</script>  </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

.CSS Code for the drop-down content class

```
/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right:0px;
    margin-top:67px;
    margin-right:20px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 125px;
    height:150px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background-image:url(../img/LocalConn.jpg);
}
```

Please help as this isn't working must be something staring at my face but can't figure any help appreciated??

Comment: missing one point on the path? `url(./img/MoodleUHConn.jpg)` must be `url(../img/MoodleUHConn.jpg)`

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` returns an array-like collection of elements, not an individual element. You should switch it to an id or use `document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-content')[0].style.backgroundImage`

Comment: Yeah sorry coped that typo but it still dosen't work.

Comment: Tried the document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-content')[0].style‌​.backgroundImage but it's still not working.

Answer (score 2):

These lines, e.g.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-content')[0].style.backgroundImage="url(./img/MoodleUHConn.jpg)";
```

need to have quotes inside url():

```
document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-content')[0].style.backgroundImage="url('./img/MoodleUHConn.jpg')";
```

Also, change this css

```
background-image:url(../img/LocalConn.jpg);
```

to

```
background-image:url('../img/LocalConn.jpg');
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `document.getElementsByClassName()` will always return an **Array** of HTML elements. So, you need to apply style to the HTML element not the array. **And `localonly` is undefined**

Your `<script>` should be like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkLocation() {
        var loctype="UH";
        if(loctype=localonly)
            document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-content')[0].style.backgroundImage="url(./img/LocalConn.jpg)";
        else if(loctype=UH)
            document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-content')[0].style.backgroundImage="url(./img/UHConn.jpg)";
        else
            document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-content')[0].style.backgroundImage="url(./img/MoodleUHConn.jpg)";
            }
</script>
```

Comment: Tried this solution also to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Your function should look like this:

```
function checkLocation(){
    var loctype = "UH"; //if your setting variable (loctype) statically then there shouldn't be any logic, because it will always return TRUE for (loctype === "UH")
    var image = (loctype === "UH") ? "url('./img/MoodleUHConn.jpg')" : (loctype === "localonly") ? "url('./img/LocalConn.jpg')" : "url('./img/MoodleUHConn.jpg')";
    document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-content')[0].style.backgroundImage = image;           
}
```

If your just trying to trigger the event, you don't need an `<a>` tag you can just use a `<div>` tag and attach an `onclick` event listener like so:

```
<div onclick="checkLocation()">Toggle Background Image</div>
```

also in your CSS the `background-image:` property in the `.dropdown-content` class needs quotes around the path like so:

```
background-image: url('../img/LocalConn.jpg');
```

Comment: Tried the above function but still not getting any image to appear.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    function checkLocation(){
    var loctype = "UH"; //if your setting variable (loctype) statically then there shouldn't be any logic, because it will always return TRUE for (loctype === "UH")
    var image = (loctype === "UH") ? "url(./img/MoodleUHConn.jpg)" : (loctype === "localonly") ? "url(./img/LocalConn.jpg)" : "url(./img/MoodleUHConn.jpg)";
    document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-content')[0].style.backgroundImage = image;           
}
</script>

Comment: @kbbkirl yes sry left the quotes inside the strings out, go ahead and run it now.